# To which distribution does the given PDF belong

Tags: probability-distributions, special-functions, bessel-functions

I have calculated the following PDF, 
$$ f(y)
=  \begin{cases} \frac{\sqrt{-y}}{2} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}-y - \frac{1}{4}}  \left( I_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right) - I_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right) \right) ,& y<0 \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} e^{ - 1/4} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right), &y=0\\
\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2} -y-\frac{1}{4}} \left(I_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right) + I_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)\right),  &y>0
 \end{cases}
$$
where $I_\nu$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first kind.

How do I find to which (if any) known distribution it belongs ?

I have searched for generalized Bessel distribution, and other similar things, but could not find anything that matches.